# Зацикленное перемещение спрайта в рамках

Tags: c#, unity3d

Внутри определенной области должны перемещаться облака(все облака это 1 спрайт).Часть спрайта,которая начинает выходить за рамки заданой области должна появляться на другом ее конце и продолжить движение и так до бесконечности.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это просто сделать при помощи нахождения остатка от деления текстурной координаты по X на 1 во фрагментном шейдере.

Текстурные координаты - пара значений от 0 до 1, прибавляем к координате по х значение времени и находим от получившегося значения остаток от деления на 1 - т.е. только дробную часть.

---

Создайте новый `unlit shader` и добавьте в код фрагментного шейдера следующее:

```
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    fixed2 uv = i.uv;
    uv.x = (uv.x + _Time.r) % 1;    
    return tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
}
```

Вот такой листинг в итоге у меня получился:

```html
Shader "Unlit/NewUnlitShader"
{
 Properties
 {
  _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
 }
 SubShader
 {
  Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
  LOD 100

  Pass
  {
   CGPROGRAM
   #pragma vertex vert
   #pragma fragment frag
   #pragma multi_compile_fog
   
   #include "UnityCG.cginc"

   struct appdata
   {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
   };

   struct v2f
   {
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
   };

   sampler2D _MainTex;
   float4 _MainTex_ST;
   
   v2f vert (appdata v)
   {
    v2f o;
    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
    return o;
   }
   
   fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
   {
       fixed2 uv = i.uv;
    uv.x = (uv.x + _Time.r) % 1; 
    return tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
   }
   ENDCG
  }
 }
}
```

Добавьте материал с этим шейдером к спрайту, установите текстуру, и вот что получится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как всегда радуете графическим подходом. В очередной раз узнал что-то новое, благодарю :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я вот думаю написать пояснения про остаток от деления или и так понятно?

Comment: Тут уже на ваше усмотрение, лично мне понятно, другим - не могу знать, но если есть время, лишнее предложение вопрос хуже явно не сделает.